# I want to check internet connection where iPhone is connected to wifi, but router isn't connected to internet

Tags: ios, swift

Here I create hotspot in other mobile. I connected iPhone with hotspot. I turned off data.
So how would i know that iPhone isn't connected to internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make swift file of *Reachability.swift*

```
import SystemConfiguration
import Foundation

public enum ReachabilityError: ErrorType {
    case FailedToCreateWithAddress(sockaddr_in)
    case FailedToCreateWithHostname(String)
    case UnableToSetCallback
    case UnableToSetDispatchQueue
}

public let ReachabilityChangedNotification = "ReachabilityChangedNotification"

func callback(reachability:SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(info)).takeUnretainedValue()

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       reachability.reachabilityChanged(flags)
   }
}


public class Reachability: NSObject {

public typealias NetworkReachable = (Reachability) -> ()
public typealias NetworkUnreachable = (Reachability) -> ()

public enum NetworkStatus: CustomStringConvertible {

    case NotReachable, ReachableViaWiFi, ReachableViaWWAN

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .ReachableViaWWAN:
            return "Cellular"
        case .ReachableViaWiFi:
            return "WiFi"
        case .NotReachable:
            return "No Connection"
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - *** Public properties ***
public var whenReachable: NetworkReachable?
public var whenUnreachable: NetworkUnreachable?
public var reachableOnWWAN: Bool
public var notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

public var currentReachabilityStatus: NetworkStatus {
    if isReachable() {
        if isReachableViaWiFi() {
            return .ReachableViaWiFi
        }
        if isRunningOnDevice {
            return .ReachableViaWWAN
        }
    }
    return .NotReachable
}

public var currentReachabilityString: String {
    return "\(currentReachabilityStatus)"
}

private var previousFlags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags?

// MARK: - *** Initialisation methods ***

required public init(reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability) {
    reachableOnWWAN = true
    self.reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef
}

public convenience init(hostname: String) throws {

    let nodename = (hostname as NSString).UTF8String
    guard let ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, nodename) else { throw ReachabilityError.FailedToCreateWithHostname(hostname) }

    self.init(reachabilityRef: ref)
}

public class func reachabilityForInternetConnection() throws -> Reachability {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let ref = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else { throw ReachabilityError.FailedToCreateWithAddress(zeroAddress) }

    return Reachability(reachabilityRef: ref)
}

public class func reachabilityForLocalWiFi() throws -> Reachability {

    var localWifiAddress: sockaddr_in = sockaddr_in(sin_len: __uint8_t(0), sin_family: sa_family_t(0), sin_port: in_port_t(0), sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(localWifiAddress))
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
    let address: UInt32 = 0xA9FE0000
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr_t(address.bigEndian)

    guard let ref = withUnsafePointer(&localWifiAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else { throw ReachabilityError.FailedToCreateWithAddress(localWifiAddress) }

    return Reachability(reachabilityRef: ref)
}

// MARK: - *** Notifier methods ***
public func startNotifier() throws {

    guard !notifierRunning else { return }

    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef!, callback, &context) {
        stopNotifier()
        throw ReachabilityError.UnableToSetCallback
    }

    if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef!, reachabilitySerialQueue) {
        stopNotifier()
        throw ReachabilityError.UnableToSetDispatchQueue
    }

    // Perform an intial check
    dispatch_async(reachabilitySerialQueue) { () -> Void in
        let flags = self.reachabilityFlags
        self.reachabilityChanged(flags)
    }

    notifierRunning = true
}

public func stopNotifier() {
    defer { notifierRunning = false }
    guard let reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef else { return }

    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, nil, nil)
    SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef, nil)
}

// MARK: - *** Connection test methods ***
public func isReachable() -> Bool {
    let flags = reachabilityFlags
    return isReachableWithFlags(flags)
}

public func isReachableViaWWAN() -> Bool {

    let flags = reachabilityFlags

    // Check we're not on the simulator, we're REACHABLE and check we're on WWAN
    return isRunningOnDevice && isReachable(flags) && isOnWWAN(flags)
}

public func isReachableViaWiFi() -> Bool {

    let flags = reachabilityFlags

    // Check we're reachable
    if !isReachable(flags) {
        return false
    }

    // Must be on WiFi if reachable but not on an iOS device (i.e. simulator)
    if !isRunningOnDevice {
        return true
    }

    // Check we're NOT on WWAN
    return !isOnWWAN(flags)
}

// MARK: - *** Private methods ***
private var isRunningOnDevice: Bool = {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        return false
    #else
        return true
    #endif
}()

private var notifierRunning = false
private var reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability?
private let reachabilitySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("uk.co.ashleymills.reachability", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

private func reachabilityChanged(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) {

    guard previousFlags != flags else { return }

    if isReachableWithFlags(flags) {
        if let block = whenReachable {
            block(self)
        }
    } else {
        if let block = whenUnreachable {
            block(self)
        }
    }

    notificationCenter.postNotificationName(ReachabilityChangedNotification, object:self)

    previousFlags = flags
}

private func isReachableWithFlags(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {

    if !isReachable(flags) {
        return false
    }

    if isConnectionRequiredOrTransient(flags) {
        return false
    }

    if isRunningOnDevice {
        if isOnWWAN(flags) && !reachableOnWWAN {
            // We don't want to connect when on 3G.
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

// WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
// WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
private func isConnectionRequired() -> Bool {
    return connectionRequired()
}

private func connectionRequired() -> Bool {
    let flags = reachabilityFlags
    return isConnectionRequired(flags)
}

// Dynamic, on demand connection?
private func isConnectionOnDemand() -> Bool {
    let flags = reachabilityFlags
    return isConnectionRequired(flags) && isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemand(flags)
}

// Is user intervention required?
private func isInterventionRequired() -> Bool {
    let flags = reachabilityFlags
    return isConnectionRequired(flags) && isInterventionRequired(flags)
}

private func isOnWWAN(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    #if os(iOS)
        return flags.contains(.IsWWAN)
    #else
        return false
    #endif
}
private func isReachable(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.Reachable)
}
private func isConnectionRequired(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
}
private func isInterventionRequired(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.InterventionRequired)
}
private func isConnectionOnTraffic(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.ConnectionOnTraffic)
}
private func isConnectionOnDemand(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.ConnectionOnDemand)
}
func isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemand(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return !flags.intersect([.ConnectionOnTraffic, .ConnectionOnDemand]).isEmpty
}
private func isTransientConnection(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.TransientConnection)
}
private func isLocalAddress(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.IsLocalAddress)
}
private func isDirect(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    return flags.contains(.IsDirect)
}
private func isConnectionRequiredOrTransient(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
    let testcase:SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = [.ConnectionRequired, .TransientConnection]
    return flags.intersect(testcase) == testcase
}

private var reachabilityFlags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags {

    guard let reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef else { return SCNetworkReachabilityFlags() }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    let gotFlags = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&flags) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }

    if gotFlags {
        return flags
    } else {
        return SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    }
}

override public var description: String {
    var W: String
    if isRunningOnDevice {
        W = isOnWWAN(reachabilityFlags) ? "W" : "-"
    } else {
        W = "X"
    }
    let R = isReachable(reachabilityFlags) ? "R" : "-"
    let c = isConnectionRequired(reachabilityFlags) ? "c" : "-"
    let t = isTransientConnection(reachabilityFlags) ? "t" : "-"
    let i = isInterventionRequired(reachabilityFlags) ? "i" : "-"
    let C = isConnectionOnTraffic(reachabilityFlags) ? "C" : "-"
    let D = isConnectionOnDemand(reachabilityFlags) ? "D" : "-"
    let l = isLocalAddress(reachabilityFlags) ? "l" : "-"
    let d = isDirect(reachabilityFlags) ? "d" : "-"
    return "\(W)\(R) \(c)\(t)\(i)\(C)\(D)\(l)\(d)"
}

deinit {
    stopNotifier()
    reachabilityRef = nil
    whenReachable = nil
    whenUnreachable = nil
}
}
```

Then configure this in your AppDelegate or any of your view controller.

```
   var reach: Reachability?
```

call this in didFinish or viewDidLoad where Notification is fired.

```
 // Reachibility defined
func configureReachability() {
    do{
        self.reach = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        try self.reach!.startNotifier()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: #selector(AppDelegate.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}



func reachabilityChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.reach!.isReachableViaWiFi() {
        //Perform the operation you want... It is connected to WiFi
    }
}
```

**Hope it works**

Comment: I created hotspot and connect my iPhone.I turned off data but wifi is still on.So How would i notice internet is not available.

Comment: I just want to know that wifi which is connected to my phone has active internet connection or not?

Comment: Means you want to say that you are connected to wifi but the wifi connection is not working.. so in this case you want to notify yourself

Comment: Or do you want get notify when your internet connection changes from data pack to WiFi.????

Comment: **i need this** Means you want to say that you are connected to wifi but the wifi connection is not working.. so in this case you want to notify yourself

Comment: (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_APLViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_APLViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7)